# How do you set the X/Y and Width/Height in pixels of UV islands?

Tags: uv

I'm trying to set the UV island to coordinate X/Y say (X=98 pixel location, y=303 pixel location) and then set the width and height of islands in PIXELS as well. I explored all the options in the menus of UV map editor but can't figure out why it is so complicated to do this "simple" task?

And when i scale the island to zero then position it to lower left corner, i can't scale it back up. it will be zero forever?

Comment: Hi :). You're right, it's odd Blender can't scale UV islands to exact pixel dimensions. And btw yes, if you scale to 0, you cannot scale back up.

Comment: There are workarounds to do such scaling, but still... why isn't it implemented directly? smh :))

Comment: @JachymMichal hey thanks for your response! yeah as a firmware engineer/programmer myself i find it odd and i don't see why it should be hard to implement. So my workaround is to zoom in really high and then move it per pixel hahaha

Comment: well, you can set the uv editor to work in pixels, then if you type G X 250 it will move selection 250px... also wrote a little test script to reset the island to bounds of the editor and then scale / move using pixels as a unit, but it needs some rounding or something to make it pixel perfect, was just a test anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Unfortunately not possible

Comment: I kind of understand why it's not a thing, let imagine you have a low resolution image and a dense mesh, if you adjust values to make it pixel perfect after a couple of transformations you begin to loose information on your uv map, some vertices weld and so on... in that case you would need 2 versions of your map, the vector one and the pixelized -like the icon preview in inkscape-