# Is it possible to exactly set a UV mapping by entering the UV values as numbers instead of clicking and dragging?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to apply a UV texture I created to a model, but I'm not satisfied by the level of precision offered by simply clicking and dragging with the mouse. I would like to be able to pick a vertex and enter by hand the specific, exact UV values I want (like [0,192]) instead of "close enough" freehanding with a mouse. Is there a way to do this?

Failing this, is there a "snap to grid" feature so that the mouse will snap to exact multiples of some value such as 32px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just figured it out.

Select the specific vertex in the UV editor and press the N key. That will open a panel on the side where you can type the exact UV coordinates. They are as a percentage of the image as opposed to exact pixel numbers (for example, 64px on a 512px texture is 0.125) but doing the math is no problem, especially as you can enter the math (like `64/512`) right there in the input field.

Comment: ah yeah i remember having the similar issue here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255810/how-do-you-set-the-x-y-and-width-height-in-pixels-of-uv-islands